# Converting a matrix of unix timestamps into human times in R

Tags: r, timestamp, unix-timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone

I've a 14 x 2 matrix of human times, called TH, as the output of an R code; however, the output of TH is as follows:

```
 [1] "2018-01-24 00:00:00 CET" "2018-01-24 00:24:34 CET" "2018-01-24 08:32:22 CET"
 [4] "2018-01-24 08:42:12 CET" "2018-01-24 09:08:24 CET" "2018-01-24 11:41:36 CET"
 [7] "2018-01-24 12:29:15 CET" "2018-01-24 12:31:47 CET" "2018-01-24 12:33:28 CET"
[10] "2018-01-24 14:32:03 CET" "2018-01-24 15:37:48 CET" "2018-01-24 16:53:36 CET"
[13] "2018-01-24 17:07:18 CET" "2018-01-24 21:10:23 CET" "2018-01-24 00:24:27 CET"
[16] "2018-01-24 08:32:15 CET" "2018-01-24 08:42:05 CET" "2018-01-24 09:08:13 CET"
[19] "2018-01-24 11:41:24 CET" "2018-01-24 12:29:08 CET" "2018-01-24 12:31:41 CET"
[22] "2018-01-24 12:33:11 CET" "2018-01-24 14:31:40 CET" "2018-01-24 15:37:25 CET"
[25] "2018-01-24 16:53:29 CET" "2018-01-24 17:07:11 CET" "2018-01-24 21:10:05 CET"
[28] "2018-01-25 00:00:00 CET"
```

I'd like to see TH as a matrix, because each row consists of start time and end time of a certain events. How could I make sure that TH displays in the matrix form, and not in the form I'm getting?

In my code, TS was a 14 x 2 matrix of unix timestamps as follows:

```
    > TS
              [,1]         [,2]
 [1,] 1.516748e+12 1.516750e+12
 [2,] 1.516750e+12 1.516779e+12
 [3,] 1.516779e+12 1.516780e+12
 [4,] 1.516780e+12 1.516781e+12
 [5,] 1.516781e+12 1.516790e+12
 [6,] 1.516790e+12 1.516793e+12
 [7,] 1.516793e+12 1.516794e+12
 [8,] 1.516794e+12 1.516794e+12
 [9,] 1.516794e+12 1.516801e+12
[10,] 1.516801e+12 1.516805e+12
[11,] 1.516805e+12 1.516809e+12
[12,] 1.516809e+12 1.516810e+12
[13,] 1.516810e+12 1.516825e+12
[14,] 1.516825e+12 1.516835e+12
```

Next I applied:

**TH = as.POSIXct(TS/1000,origin="1970-01-01",tz="Europe/Paris")**

to obtain TH, but it always outputs in the above form. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you mean `data.frame` rather than `matrix`?

Comment: please send a sample of your original matrix

Comment: `matrix(TH, ncol=2)` ?

Comment: matrix can only store numerical values. Timestamp is a date/time object, hence, not numerical

Comment: Please put the result of `dput(TH)` in your question!

Comment: @chinsoon12, thanks, my mistake, yes indeed a data frame.

Comment: @Seymour Sorry I didn't really mean a matrix. I've just started learning R.  meant I'd like a table of events where the first columns will bt eht human time of the the first column in TS  (in the question) and the second column as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your vector looks like this:

```
temp <- c("2018-01-24 00:00:00 CET", "2018-01-24 00:24:34 CET", "2018-01-24 08:32:22 CET",
      "2018-01-24 08:42:12 CET", "2018-01-24 09:08:24 CET", "2018-01-24 11:41:36 CET",
      "2018-01-24 12:29:15 CET", "2018-01-24 12:31:47 CET", "2018-01-24 12:33:28 CET",
      "2018-01-24 14:32:03 CET", "2018-01-24 15:37:48 CET", "2018-01-24 16:53:36 CET",
      "2018-01-24 17:07:18 CET", "2018-01-24 21:10:23 CET", "2018-01-24 00:24:27 CET",
      "2018-01-24 08:32:15 CET", "2018-01-24 08:42:05 CET", "2018-01-24 09:08:13 CET",
      "2018-01-24 11:41:24 CET", "2018-01-24 12:29:08 CET", "2018-01-24 12:31:41 CET",
      "2018-01-24 12:33:11 CET", "2018-01-24 14:31:40 CET", "2018-01-24 15:37:25 CET",
      "2018-01-24 16:53:29 CET", "2018-01-24 17:07:11 CET", "2018-01-24 21:10:05 CET",
      "2018-01-25 00:00:00 CET")

temp <- (lubridate::ymd_hms(temp, tz = "CET"))
```

Then you can transform it to a character vector before turning it to a matrix:

```
mat <- matrix(as.character(temp), ncol = 2)
mat
```

now if you want to do some date/time manipulations you need to make it a data frame

```
df <- data.frame(mat)
```

and then you can cast the date type:

```
df$X1 <- lubridate::ymd_hms(df$X1, tz = "CET")
df$X2 <- lubridate::ymd_hms(df$X2, tz = "CET")
```

Comment: Thank you, mat <- matrix(as.character(temp), ncol = 2)
mat >worked like a charm!